# EDK2: Sign startup.nsh EUFI script

Tags: boot, uefi, secure-boot, signature

When the BIOS loads the EDK2 UEFI shell it checks it's signature. Then I've configured EDK2 to verify all EUFI modules (i.e. Ext4Pkg), but the startup.nsh script is unsigned.

How can I sign/verify the file and check it in EDK2?